# Issues on expiration of laravel 4.2 session

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

in my login i have created sessions, `Session::put('lid','somevalue')` and `Session::put('ltype','somevalue')` and in my default blade i did something like

```
@if(Session->has('ltype')
<div>Hello</div>
@else
//redirect to login page
```

in my session.php in app/config i already changed the timeout to 5 meaning 5 minutes. i timed it but its already 8 minutes when i refreshed my page it still displayed `Hello` where it should be redirected to the login already because the session is expired already. am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
    @if(Session::has('ltype')
        <div>Hello</div>
    @else
```

you must use `::` instead of `->` because Session is a static method.

Comment: hi! sorry my bad. i did that but somehow i'm still going inside the if statement

Comment: hmm it did went to the @else statement but had some 2-3 minute delay

Comment: @BourneShady For performance purposes, sessions are not evaluated on every request to determine if they expired. They use a lottery to determine if the check should be made, so if you refresh a few times, garbage collector will eventually be triggered and clean the expired sessions. That's why you experienced the delay. You can read more about that in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744921/laravel-4-2-session-table-not-getting-cleaned-up/26745685#26745685).

Comment: Thanks for you too @BourneShady